# Active transactions on a specific time every day using 'start date' and 'end date'

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to calculate the number of active transactions on the first of each month at a specific time. I can calculate that for a specific day for the time I want. For example I can run:

```
SELECT 
A.country_code,
A.transaction_type,
COUNT (*)

FROM table A
JOIN table_history h ON h.listing_id = A.listing_id

WHERE h.start_date <= '2017-12-01 08:01:03' and NVL(h.end_date, '31-DEC-2099') >= '2017-12-01 08:01:03'

GROUP BY 
A.country_code,
A.transaction_type
```

That code works fine for the first of December. However, I want to expand that to get all active transactions at that specific time (08:01:03) for every first of the month.

Thank you

Comment: `nvl`?.. postgres uses `coalesce` did you create function yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to sort it out by bringing in a Dim Date table and creating a complicated join:

```
SELECT 
A.country_code,
A.transaction_type,
COUNT (*)

FROM table A
JOIN table_history h ON h.listing_id = A.listing_id

JOIN dim_date dd  on h.start_date <= DATEADD(m,1,DATEADD(hour,8,dd.date)) and NVL(h.end_date, '31-DEC-2099') >= DATEADD(m,1,DATEADD(hour,8,dd.date))

WHERE dd.month_day_no = 1
--WHERE h.start_date <= '2017-12-01 08:01:03' and NVL(h.end_date, '31-DEC-2099') >= '2017-12-01 08:01:03'

GROUP BY 
A.country_code,
A.transaction_type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a timestamp as a time to get just the time and use `extract` to get the day of the month:

```
where
  cast (start_date as time) = '08:01:03' and
  extract (day from start_date) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I can't use 'cast (start_date as time)' because I'm querying Redshift tables.
Also, I need the <= start date in addition to the >= end date to get the active transactions on that specific time